# databricks load file from s3 bucket path parameter

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

I am new to databricks or spark and learning this demo from databricks. I have a databricks workspace setup on AWS.
The code below is from the official demo and it runs ok. But where is this csv file? I want to check the file and also understand how the path parameter works.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diamonds;

CREATE TABLE diamonds
USING csv
OPTIONS (path "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", 
         header "true")
```

I have checked at the databrikcs location on S3 bucket and have not found the file:
[image]

Comment: the path could be either on the databricks cluster itself or could be on the dbfs location.  What is the official demo that you are following? Can you add the reference of it so that someone could help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/databricks-datasets` is a special [mount](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#mount-object-storage-to-dbfs) location that is **owned by Databricks** and available out of box in all workspaces. You can't browse it via S3 browser, but you can use `display(dbutils.fs.ls("/databricks-datasets"))`, or `%fs ls /databricks-datasets`, or DBFS File browser (in "Data" tab) to explore its content - see a [separate page about it](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-datasets.html).

Comment: I remember that a S3 bucket (client account) is used for any dbfs work so shouldn't these datasets be stored in client s3 now ?

Comment: No.  S3 bucket is used to create DBFS root, but then you can attach additional mounts to DBFS. The content of `/databricks-datasets` isn't copied into DBFS root, you can just use it

Comment: thanks for clarification!